# Validation inside the insertitemtemplate or edititemtemplate of detailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is whenever I put validation controls in the *insertitemtemplate* OR *edititemtemplate* of fields for validation inside the *detailsView*,neither validation nor postback happens. In this case when i hover my mouse over insert link then it say *postbackwithoption* but when I click on the link, nothing happen

And if I remove validation controls post back happen. In this case when i hover my mouse over insert link then it say  *postback*.

I spent a lot of time on google found following solution but nothing worked for me

1.Setting cause validation to false for insert link

2.Setting Groupvalidation for controls and insert link

I am using visual studio 2012 and newbie in asp.net

Thanks

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted" OnItemInserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" OnItemUpdating="DetailsView1_ItemUpdating">
<Fields>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter a title" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter a title" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="Summary">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter a summary" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter a summary" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" runat="server" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
      </Fields>
```

Comment: Can u pls share some code snippet

Comment: I added the source to my question.Actually the problem i stated only occur if i add the validation controls to any of the template field.